# How do I get a three-hour rolling average while grouping by each hour?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of phone calls. It has these columns: start_time, type, duration.

I have a query that gets the average call duration for each hour:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00') as h,
    t1.type,
    AVG(t1.duration)
FROM
    phone_calls t1

WHERE
    t1.start_time > '2015-09-02 00:00'
    AND t1.duration is not null
GROUP BY
    t1.type,
    h
ORDER BY
    h asc
```

Instead of getting the average of the hour, I would like to get the average of the past three hours for each hour.

I tried this which didn't work:

```
SELECT
    h,
    type,
    (

        SELECT
            dur_sum * dur_count / SUM(dur_count) rolling_avg
        FROM(
            SELECT
                CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00') as h,
                t1.type,
                SUM(t1.duration),
                COUNT(t1.duration)
            FROM
                phone_calls t1

            WHERE
                t1.start_time > '2015-09-02 00:00'
                AND t1.duration is not null
            GROUP BY
                t1.type,
                h
            ORDER BY
                h asc
        ) as q1
        WHERE
            h BETWEEN DATE_SUB(h, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) AND h
    ) as rolling
FROM(
    SELECT
        CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00') as h,
        t1.type,
        SUM(t1.duration),
        COUNT(t1.duration)
    FROM
        phone_calls t1

    WHERE
        t1.start_time > '2015-09-02 00:00'
        AND t1.duration is not null
    GROUP BY
        t1.type,
        h
    ORDER BY
        h asc
) as q2
```

That query gave me the same value for the rolling column for all the rows. How would I change my query to get what I'm looking for? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's what my first query returns:

```
h                 , type ,t_avg    
"2015-09-02 00:00", 2    ,773.5000    
"2015-09-02 00:00", 3    ,246.7966  
"2015-09-02 00:00", 1    ,377.4337  
"2015-09-02 01:00", 1    ,258.7692  
"2015-09-02 01:00", 3    ,188.9737  
"2015-09-02 02:00", 3    ,144.6471  
"2015-09-02 02:00", 1    ,254.4400  
"2015-09-02 03:00", 1    ,67.9048  
"2015-09-02 03:00", 3    ,88.9333
```

etc

Here's some sample data from the table itself:

```
start_time            ,type ,duration  
"2015-09-02 00:00:11" ,3    ,174  
"2015-09-02 00:00:15" ,1    ,1088  
"2015-09-02 00:00:27" ,1    ,23  
"2015-09-02 00:00:43" ,3    ,125  
"2015-09-02 00:00:52" ,1    ,31  
"2015-09-02 00:01:05" ,3    ,21  
"2015-09-02 00:01:16" ,1    ,43  
"2015-09-02 00:01:40" ,1    ,88  
"2015-09-02 00:02:17" ,1    ,117  
"2015-09-02 00:04:06" ,1    ,22  
"2015-09-02 00:04:13" ,1    ,46  
"2015-09-02 00:04:15" ,1    ,116  
"2015-09-02 00:04:29" ,3    ,57  
"2015-09-02 00:04:44" ,3    ,728  
"2015-09-02 00:04:57" ,3    ,132
```

This is what I want from the data:

```
h                 , type ,rolling_avg    
"2015-09-02 00:00", 2    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 2>     
"2015-09-02 00:00", 3    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 3>  
"2015-09-02 00:00", 1    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 1>  
"2015-09-02 01:00", 1    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 1>  
"2015-09-02 01:00", 3    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 3>  
"2015-09-02 02:00", 3    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 3>  
"2015-09-02 02:00", 1    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 1>  
"2015-09-02 03:00", 1    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 1>  
"2015-09-02 03:00", 3    ,<average duration for past three hours for type 3>
```

Comment: Some sample data will help a lot. Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do you mean a single average for last 3 hours, or 3 avg for h1, h2, h3 ? Also if a call start in h1 and last for more than 60 min the average only affect h1 or will affect h2?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I mean 3 avg for h1, h2, h3. It will only affect h1. The call should only count for when it starts.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Thanks for making the data easier to read. I couldn't figure out how to make a table.

Comment: no problem ... need add 4 spaces before the line.

Comment: Looks like your data isn't complete. Only show data from `00h`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes the data is not complete. It's just a sample to give you an idea of what it looks like. If I were to post the complete data, there would be thousands upon thousands of rows.

Comment: Did you read my first link?, you have to post at least something minimal, complete and veriiable. Of course not all data, but something to work with.

Comment: Yea, there's enough data there. You can change the times to be different hours or whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, of course I can. But Im not the one asking the question. Imagine I invent data and then you say that case doesn't exist? I will lose my time for nothing.

Comment: I mean in this case the data doesn't really matter. Invent whatever data you'd like as long as there is a timestamp column and a column for some sort of value.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you the easy way. Because dont have the schema.

If already have average by hour just add `count` field

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00') as h,
    t1.type,
    AVG(t1.duration) t_avg,
    COUNT(t1.duration) t_count
```

ADD a limit and order by

```
ORDER BY h
LIMIT 3
```

Then over that query

```
SELECT SUM( t_avg * t_count ) / SUM( t_count )
FROM <previous query>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This only gets me the average for the past three hours. I would like the three-hour average for each hour in the past X number of hours. I will add some sample data to the original question. I do have a list of the columns in my table in the post though.

Comment: Yes, you have to explain what `the three-hour average for each hour` mean. That mean `avg(h1,h2,h3)` +  `avg(h2,h3,h4)` + `avg(h3,h4,h5)`  ... etc ?

Comment: I must say if you read your question say `I would like to get the average of the past three hours.`

Comment: It means a 3 hour rolling average. I edited the question to try and make it a little more clear.

Comment: Sorry Im not familiar with the term `rolling average` If you could show your expected output will be great. Also in your first query I think you mean `group by t1.type`

Comment: Yea I did mean `group by t1.type`. It was a typo. I added a chart of the data I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Just Union your table 3 times with

```
Union all
```

the first is :

```
(select CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.start_time), '%Y-%m-%d %H'), ':00') as h,
    t1.type,duration from phone_calls t1)
```

and the second with date_add of interval - 1 hour
and the third with date_add of interval - 2 hour

After that run an external query : `select h,type,avg(duration) from q1 group by h,type`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this: "and the second with date_add of interval - 1 hour and the third with date_add of interval - 2 hour"

Comment: You set each daytime row to 1 and 2 hours beofre Respectively